# Writing to a property file formatting errors

Tags: java, format, property-files

If I write to a property file and use a "\" or a ":" java produces a backslash before the character in the property file. I've tried putting a backslash before the character to cancel it out, that doesn't work.

Ex:

```
props.setProperty("outputFolder", "D:\\src");
```

This produces D\:\\src in the property file.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: what is the required string , Please specify that also?

Comment: That's how the property file format is defined to work. You can't change that - it wouldn't be a proper propertyfile anymore. See the file format: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s0204propertiesfileformat01.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this and check you will get what you wanted to store --`props.get("outputFolder")`